# Eclipse - how to setup plugin run configuration to run it inside custom Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

When you create new Plug-in project inside Eclipse, you can run it as Eclipse Application (eg. new Eclipse instance will start with that plugin included by default).

I need start that plugin but in instance of my own Eclipse RCP app (which i have as other project in my workspace).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open 'Run > Run Configurations' and find the configuration for your RCP application (under 'Eclipse Application')

Look at the 'Plug-ins' tab.

If the 'Launch with:' is set to 'all workspace and enabled target plugins' your plugin is already being included.

If the 'Launch with:' is set to 'plug-ins selected below only' select the plugin you want to include if it is not already selected.