# Newly added UI Plugin not getting activated in eclipse runtime

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created a new eclipse plugin, new extensions and also defined a new extension point in an Eclipse Plugin which will be contributing to the UI.

When I test the plugin from plugin.xml option "Test this plugin by launching a separate eclipse application" or "Run as eclipse application" (in Run Configurations), the plugin will get activated and my extensions gets loaded.

However, when I execute the Eclipse runtime/debug from this other run/debug configuration which is defined for our eclipse product, then this newly added plugin won't get loaded.

Let me know how can I check the root cause of this plugin not getting loaded.

I have ensured that plugin.xml is correctly configured. I also checked this Platform.getExtensionRegistry().getConfigurationElementsFor(extensionPointId) will not contain the extension which I have defined.

Comment: Does _Clear the configuration area before launching_ (in the launch configuration, in the tab _Configuration_) fix your issue?

Comment: This option in the configuration tab and is already checked. Hence it clears the configuration every time.



What I figured is that when I launch the runtime eclipse with "Run as eclipse application" it will load my plugin.

However, when I launch it with this other run configuration my plugin won't load. This run configuration has been defined for the code base\runtime eclipse product I am working with. I wonder if I am supposed to add this newly created plugin to this particular runtime configuration? Any thoughts?

Comment: Then I guess the plug-in is not selected in that launch configuration in the tab _Plug-ins_ (or maybe the plug-in from the target platform instead of the workspace is selected).

Comment: I figured out that the particular runtime config is only loading a specific plugins in the form of features and my plugin is not defined in there. I chnaged the setting as per this ticket to 



If the 'Launch with:' is set to 'all workspace and enabled target plugins' your plugin is already being included.

[link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26532172/eclipse-how-to-setup-plugin-run-configuration-to-run-it-inside-custom-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You are right there, I found out that my plugin was not added to the feature.xml for this run configuration. I have added the entries for the new plugin and now the new plugins are also getting loaded! Thanks for the insights!